# Trace inequality of Hadmard product

Tags: linear-algebra, inequality, trace, cauchy-schwarz-inequality, hadamard-product

For any Hermitian matrix $\bf A$ and invertible matrix $\bf B$, how do I derive the inequality below
$${\rm tr}(({\bf B}^H{\bf A}{\bf B}) \circ({\bf B}^H{\bf A}{\bf B}))\geq \lambda_{\min}^4({\bf B}){\rm tr}({\bf A}^2),$$
where $\circ$ denotes the Hadmard product.

I have changed the question.

Answer (score 1):

This inequality is false. Take $\mathbf{B} = \mathbf{I}$ and $\mathbf{A} = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 1\end{bmatrix}$. Then

$$
\begin{align}
\mathrm{LHS} &= \operatorname{tr} \left( \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 1\end{bmatrix} \right) = 2, \\
\mathrm{RHS} &= \lambda_{\rm min}^4(\mathbf{I})\operatorname{tr}\left( \begin{bmatrix} 2 & 2 \\ 2 & 2\end{bmatrix} \right) = 4.
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Thank you, I think at least I need add 1/size(B) as the coefficient of RHS.